# how to add new column in ms access by matching values

Tags: sql, ms-access

in an ms access database with two tables

```
TableA
MSN     PR1
12      A
13      B
11      C
14      X

TableB
MSN     PR2
14      L
12      M
13      O
11      X
```

how can i write an sql query so that PR2 columns gets added to TableA but only after matching the MSN values . so the final TableC would be

```
TableC
MSN     PR1   PR2
12      A      M
13      B      O
11      C      X
14      X      L
```

any help appreciated

Comment: Why do you need table C? 

SELECT tableA.MSN, tableA.pr1, tableB.pr2 FROM tableA INNER JOIN tableB on tableA.MSN = tableB.MSN

Comment: Geez - a "column" only ever has one "l" in it !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a named query with the SQL: `SELECT * FROM TableA JOIN TableB USING (MSN)`, or if you prefer `SELECT * FROM TableA, TableB WHERE TableA.MSN = TableB.MSN`